# How to verify that all dependency libraries for PostGIS are installed correctly and working correctly?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, unit-testing, build, scenario-testing

I am attempting yet again to build PostGIS from the source to enable the fabled address-standardizer and the reverse-geocoder plugins for PostgreSQL.

I have carefully discovered the source repositories for all the dependencies as listed in the PostGIS manual and I have created local git repositories for each of these.

I will attempt to 'make' them as described on a Linux server machine running ubuntu 18.04. I have already installed PostgreSQL 12.2 from the PostgreSQL.org downloads, along with the server and client tools and additional developer downloads for PostgreSQL.

However, if they build, I would like to also be able to verify they are working as expected. As an experienced developer, I would expect to be able to locate a set of prepared unit tests for this type of requirement.

Does such a suite of 'build tests' exist for the entire group of dependencies listed in the PostGIS manual?

Are there instructions for setting up such tests in the Eclipse CPP implementation?

Are there any workarounds for verifying the operation of dependencies that have no test suites?

Is there a 'standard method' for verifying the operational validity of a CPP project built by one or more make versions that I should be searching for?

I have been using the O'Reilly book service as a source of technical guidance for many years. However, I have been unable to compose a search filter to locate books that possess content that addresses this question.

If any of these questions have 'no' as their answer, or if 'unknown' is the answer, I would be concerned that it will be impossible for me to trust the PostGIS extensions that were compiled according to the instructions in the latest PostGIS 3.02/3 manual.

Is that a reasonable conclusion to make, if I am faced with such an unverifiable situation.